# How to enable Flutter intentions (IDE shortcuts) in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I've been [reading](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ide-shortcuts-for-faster-development-2ef45c51085b) about IDE shortcuts to make Flutter programming easier in Android Studio, but when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click the yellow light bulb in the fringe) the only item in my context menu is "Adjust code style settings" (no "Add padding", "Wrap with Container", "Remove widget", etc.).

From what I can tell these are called "Intentions" in Android Studio. In my intentions settings I don't see anything for "Flutter". How do I get those added?

Screenshots:

[image: Missing shortcuts]

[image: Unfluttered intentions]

Comment: as I know it must be enabled by default. did you try this shortcut on other widgets as well? because I sometimes have this problem with one random widget

Comment: Usually, you only have to close and reopen the project

Comment: @faroukosama that was it! `/facepalm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAH! As suggested by `@faroukosama` in the comments, all I needed to do was close and reopen the project...

*Have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in?*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Could you try this way:

- Use the terminal: flutter clean -> flutter upgrade -> ( my version upgraded )
- I think you should remove flutter and download again
  Hope it works for you!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by
[Duong Quang Son](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/can-t-wrap-widget-list-with-new-widget-assist-by-alt+enter-2448)

make sure you have checked 
**Editor** -> **Intentions** -> **Quick assist powered by the Dart Analysis Server.**

[image]